# Mock instance inside serde implementation

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking, serde

I'm trying to implement custom deserialization function/method which uses some external functionality. The function creates an instance and uses its methods. It's working fine, but I can't figure out how to mock the service in tests.

More general question is: how to provide a state to deserialization function/method?

The code below illustrates what I mean.

`MagickBook` is an external service which holds a state and contains some essential logic in `MagickBook::find` method.

`Scroll` is a deserializable data structure, which should be deserialized using the logic from `MagicBook`.

I'd like to have a way to provide particular instance of `MagicBook` from the outside, at the moment of deserialization. For example in tests.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e73f3bce34f6746a7f360260a0c524c)

```rust
use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.82
use serde_derive::Deserialize; // 1.0.82
use serde_json; // 1.0.33

struct MagickBook;

// Some service which I want to mock in the test
impl MagickBook {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }

    fn find(&self, _kind: &str) -> isize {
        let effect = 42;
        // Here we do some logic depending on input parameter
        // -- snip --
        return effect;
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Scroll {
    #[serde(rename = "kind")]
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_effect")]
    effect: isize,
}

fn deserialize_effect<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<isize, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let book = MagickBook::new();
    Ok(book.find(&String::deserialize(deserializer)?))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn main() {
        let scroll: Scroll = serde_json::from_str("{\"kind\":\"wind\"}").unwrap();
        assert_eq!(scroll, Scroll { effect: 42 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend accessing the mock through an internally mutable thread-local instance.

---

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct MagickBook {
    value: isize,
}

thread_local! {
    static MAGICK_BOOK: RefCell<MagickBook> = RefCell::new(MagickBook::new());
}

impl MagickBook {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MagickBook { value: 0 }
    }

    fn find(&self, _kind: &str) -> isize {
        let effect = self.value;
        // -- snip --
        effect
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Scroll {
    #[serde(rename = "kind", deserialize_with = "deserialize_effect")]
    effect: isize,
}

fn deserialize_effect<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<isize, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let kind = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    Ok(MAGICK_BOOK.with(|book| book.borrow().find(&kind)))
}

#[test]
fn test_deserialize() {
    MAGICK_BOOK.with(|book| book.borrow_mut().value = 42);
    let scroll: Scroll = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"kind":"wind"}"#).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(scroll, Scroll { effect: 42 });
}
```